# How to get rid of this error? "Runtime Error 1004 Method Range ofobject_Global Failed in VBA"

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code below. I am trying to get a difference between sums of a range of data from 2 different worksheets. I have already achieved that. My next goal is to get two strings from two different sheets in the same workbook, which, when concatenated, give my the cell address where I should save the result of the calculations. I haven't been able to achieve the same thanks to the error mentioned in the question.

```
Sub Prob3()
    Worksheets("Problem3").Activate
    Worksheets("Problem3").Name = "Q3"
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rngSum As Single
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String
    Dim OP As Range
    Dim strCombo As String
    Set rngA = Range("C2:C5")
    A = Range("A1").Value
    Worksheets("Problem4").Activate
    B = Range("A1").Value
    Set rngB = Range("C2:C5")
    Worksheets("Q3").Activate
    rngSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngA) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngB)
    Worksheets("Q3").Activate
    strCombo = A & B
    Range("Z7").Value = strCombo
    Set OP = Range(Range("Z7").Value)
    Range(OP).Value = rngSum
End Sub
```

I am getting an error at this line:
`Range(OP).Value = rngSum`

Comment: And what is the value of `OP` when it errors? Maybe you meant `OP.Value = rngSum`

Comment: well, the value of OP is supposed to be the cell address B3, which is saved in strCombo -> Z7

Comment: `OP` is defined as a `Range`, not a `String`.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: `Range(strCombo).Value = rngSum` ??? What is the value of `strCombo` when it breaks? Whare the values of `A` and `B` when it breaks? You need to do some basic debugging as people here do not have your data. Do you understand how to set break points and step thru your code and check the values?

Comment: Thank You braX. I had indeed tried this before directly, but I had faced with some error then. This time, it worked, just as intended.

Comment: strCombo =-- (A & B)